# Python Get Request All Pages Movie list

Tags: python, python-requests

While using below snippet it is not returning values of Page, Total page and data.
Also not returning the value of function "getMovieTitles".

```
import request     
import json


def getMovieTitles(substr):
    titles = []
    url = "https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/movies/search/?Title={}'.format(substr)"
    data = requests.get(url)
    print(data)
    response = json.loads(data.content.decode('utf-8'))
    print(data.content)
    for page in range(0, response['total_pages']):
        page_response = requests.get("https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/movies/search/?Title={}}&amp;page={}".format(substr, page + 1))
        page_content = json.loads(page_response.content.decode('utf-8'))

        print ('page_content', page_content, 'type(page_content)', type(page_content))

        for item in range(0, len(page_content['data'])):
            titles.append(str(page_content['data'][item]['Title']))
    titles.sort()  
    return titles

print(getMovieTitles('Superman'))
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post so the code is properly indented. It changes the meaning in python.

Comment: Hope its fine now!

Comment: You are using import request  i think you intended  import requests

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) license, for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question).

Answer (score 0):

First, import

```
import requests
```

The problem is in your string formatting

' instead of "

```
url = "https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/movies/search/?Title={}".format(substr)
```

and one } too much

```
page_response = requests.get("https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/movies/search/?Title={}&amp;page={}".format(substr, page + 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not formatting the url string correctly.

```py
url = "https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/movies/search/?Title={}'.format(substr)"
```

`format()` is a method of `string` and you've put it inside of the `url` string, instead do:

```
url = "https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/movies/search/?Title={}".format(substr)
```